# Mapbox Geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mapbox

I recently added Mapbox's Geocoder Control and it works wonderfully. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could have a marker appear at the location of the address that was searched for? Below is the code I'm currently using for the control.

```
.addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
    position: 'topright',
    keepOpen: false,
    autocomplete: false
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to register a listener for `select` event:

```
geocoder_control.on('select', function(object){
    var coord = object.feature.geometry.coordinates;

    //create and add your marker
});
```

I've made an example for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/joOXJ6?p=preview